# What words can I use in place of "background" in my sentence

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I have held multiple jobs in multiple fields in my life, such as teaching, tech jobs, philanthropy etc.

I have a sentence construction, which goes like this

> I am grateful to have known people of diverse educational backgrounds and **corporate background**.

Educational background is a fairly common phrase, on the other hand, I am fairly sure that diverse corporate background is incorrect.

I want to know what phrase can I use -in my given context- to convey the meaning the I know Tech engineers, Business Managers,Venture Capitalists,Corporate Lawyers etc.

The professions listed are just for examples sake.

Comment: Maybe *corporate experience*.

Comment: You only need **one phrase**"diverse educational and corporate backgrounds.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, that was exactly the answer I was going to post.

Comment: Minor detail: depending on exactly what you are trying to say, "educational" may not be as accurate as "academic". Given your context,  the former suggests what kind of education a person has had—which colleges they attended, what subjects they studied, etc. By contrast, the latter would point more to which colleges they worked at, what kind of work it was, etc. As I say, depends on exactly which "background" you mean.